# how to get surface nodes using Abaqus python?

Tags: abaqus

I used to use getBoundingBox() to get surface nodes if outside surface is flat. Now if the surface is not flat, what alternative method I can use to select nodes on the outside surface?? Thanks a lot

```
    bottom_face=modelInstane.nodes.getByBoundingBox(xMin=X_tolernce*-1,xMax=Model_Width_I+X_tolernce,
                        yMin=Y_tolernce*-1,yMax=Model_Width_J+Y_tolernce,zMin=ZBot_Under-Z_tolernce,zMax=ZBot_Under+Z_tolernce)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in Abaqus this type of action could require different approaches for different situations (depending on the geometry). Apart from `getByBounding...` methods you also have `getElemFacesByFaceAngle`/`getNodesByFeatureEdge`  and similar. You could also think about more particular methods like creating a set using nodes labels (if you know them), using boolean operations, using colors (sic!) and so on. So if you give an example of your geometry, and explain particularities of your task you could get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you Roman, those are exactly what I was searching for to know more methods instead of just getByBounding. I will go explore it. Thank for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a mesh surface already exists in the model, then you can use:

```
# Considering "mesh_surf" is the mesh surface name.
inst = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Part-1-1']
surf = inst.surfaces['mesh_surf']
surf_nodes = surf.nodes
```

Mesh surface is a surface associated with the mesh and NOT the geometry. 
Mesh surface is created using element faces internally and geometry surface created using geometry faces.

Comment: Thanks Satish. great code. My model is imported using partfromodb(), so the instance surface is not imported. so I don't have surface available. since the imported model has deformed geometry. That is why using geBoundingBox() is not working well for deformed surfaces. Any other option? Thanks

Comment: When you import a part using `PartFromOdb()`, Abaqus import node sets, element sets and surfaces ONLY from `Part` and NOT from the `Assembly` of the ODB. Therefore, if you can create a surface at `Part` level, you can access it from the imported `Part`.